# $C^2 $embedded in holder space?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a question on Holder space.Is the space $C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ embedded in $C^{1,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? I think in the bounded domain case, this should be true. But what if in the case where the domain is not bounded? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will give you a hint, which says $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset C^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any fixed $0<\alpha<1$.

The goal is just to bound the exponent $\alpha$ Hölder coefficient for any $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ functions $u$: choose a fixed $0<\epsilon<1$
$$
| u |_{C^{0,\alpha}} = \sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{| u(x) - u(y) |}{|x-y|^\alpha}
\\
= \max\left\{
\sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}^n,|x-y|\leq \epsilon} \frac{| u(x) - u(y) |}{|x-y|^\alpha}, \sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}^n,|x-y|>\epsilon} \frac{| u(x) - u(y) |}{|x-y|^\alpha}\right\}.
$$
Now the first quotient is bounded by the $C^1$-seminorm because $|x-y|<|x-y|^{\alpha}$ for $|x-y|<\epsilon<1$:
$$
\sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}^n,|x-y|\leq \epsilon} \frac{| u(x) - u(y) |}{|x-y|^\alpha} < \sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}^n,|x-y|\leq \epsilon} \frac{| u(x) - u(y) |}{|x-y|} = | u |_{C^{1}}.
$$
The second one is naturally bounded using triangle inequality
$$
\sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}^n,|x-y|>\epsilon} \frac{| u(x) - u(y) |}{|x-y|^\alpha}
< \sup_{x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}^n,|x-y|>\epsilon}
\frac{|u(x)|+|u(y)|}{\epsilon^\alpha} \leq \frac{2}{\epsilon^\alpha} \|u\|_{C^0}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have a question. Does the function in $C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ have bounded seminorms $C^0$, $C^1$ and $C^2$? The function I want to define is just twice differentiable. I guess for funcion like $f(x)=x^2$, it is twice differentiable but do not have bounded deriatives. I guess I might have some misunderstanding.

Comment: @piano Yeah. $\|f\|_{C^2} = \sum_{| \alpha| \leq 2} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} |D^\alpha f (x) |$. The sum could be taking maximum as well. All derivatives (and itself) must be bounded (in the whole space instead of a bounded or compact set). $x^2$ is not.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer!